# What does "localhost | FAILED => Missing become password" mean? How do I get past it?

Tags: ansible

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine set up in virtualbox and I am trying to follow these instructions.

https://serversforhackers.com/an-ansible-tutorial

When I get to the module section and try to install nginx with this command. with "local" being set to "localhost" in /etc/ansible/hosts

```
ansible local -s -m shell -a 'apt-get install nginx'
```

I get the following error:

```
localhost | FAILED => Missing become password
```

I have searched google for a way to get past this, but I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

This was a fresh install of the Server OS, and the only setup was done is in this tutorial.

Comment: Sounds like the account you're running as doesn't have `sudo` privileges.

Comment: It does.  It's the account made at software installation.  I even made it so it doesn't require a password because I thought that may have been related to the problem

Comment: see my answer to the question, it is related to sudo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is related to sudo. In `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` there is a commented out setting called `ask_sudo_pass` which needs to be uncommented out and set to `Yes`. Alternatively you can set the group the user belongs to to be able to use `sudo` without a password, but that's a security risk in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

There was a bug introduced in Ansible 1.9 that may be the cause:
[ask_sudo_pass in ansible.cfg has no effect #10891](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/10891)

Answer (score -1):

Setting the below parameter in `ansible.cfg` promoted me to enter the sudo password

```
ask_sudo_pass= true
```